# How do i create customized product in shopify

Tags: php, content-management-system, e-commerce, shopify

I want to make a website where I want to add almost the same functionality as in http://shop.dodocase.com/option/custom-ipad-cases 
This site is also developed in Shopify but I could not find such customized product option there in. May be an extension is added into shopify but which extension? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dodo case is a custom shop. Since Shopify is nothing but HTML, CSS and Javascript, you're free to customize your theme to match whatever functionality you need. You have access to certain client-side conveniences with the Shopify Ajax API for front-end development, and the Shopify API for App support.

You will probably not find a plugin or cheap solution to mimic Dodo case. There are some product customization Apps out there but your situation may not be suitable for them.

Comment: Dodo case is indeed a Shopify store. [Dodo Case](https://dodocase.myshopify.com/admin/auth/login)
They developed this custom application on Shopify. It is slow loading but it performs well.

Comment: I believe they used the services of [ryanfosterdesign.com](http://shopifyplus.ryanfosterdesign.com/) to develop their product builder.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the new Shopify app [Product Builder](http://apps.shopify.com/product-builder) by [Bold Apps](http://www.boldapps.net/) would suit your needs. It was only just released so I haven't tested it out yet, but it looks promising.